# Approve Wordpress post by multiple editors

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, publish

I'm working on a Wordpress website where contributors can upload there media campaigns. The contributors won't be able to publish their posts.

The moderators (editor role) will be able to check the posts and publish them.

There will be 4 moderators in total. When 3 of the 4 moderators approved the post, the post will be published. I only found 1 plugin that does exactly what we want: https://wordpress.org/plugins/publish-approval/

But it seems that this one doesn't work in Wordpress 5.x
Anyone else has another solution or fix for this?

It seems that the "approve" button isn't shown anymore in the Gutenberg editor.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, we found a solution for this.
So we a contributor submits a post, the status of the post is set to "pending". The publish approval plugin only checks if the status is not "draft".

So I've added an extra condition in the HandleApproval.php file.

```
if (($post->post_status !== 'draft') || ($post->post_status !== 'pending')) {
    return;
}
```